# How do I get my discord bot to react to my messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a poll feature for my discord bot. I'm trying for it to react to my message with yes and no when I run the poll feature.

```
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx,*,args):
    no = "❌"
    yes = "☑️"
    await ctx.message.delete()
    user_poll = ctx.send(args)
    await user_poll
    await user_poll.message.add_reaction(no)
    await user_poll.message.add_reaction(yes)
```

I am getting the error, Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like `await user_poll` as it tries to send the message in the moment the variable is defined. Also the `user_poll` variable is already a message object so you don't have to add a `.message` after it. And as you don't need `args` as an optional argument you can remove `*` as it also then would only take the last part of the message the user wants to have a poll for.

Revised:

```py
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, args):
    no = "❌"
    yes = "☑️"
    await ctx.message.delete()
    user_poll = await ctx.send(args)
    await user_poll.add_reaction(no)
    await user_poll.add_reaction(yes)
```

What I guess how the error came up is that maybe a previous error occurred or you (or anyone else) deleted it.

Comment: Thanks so much but if you want it to put more than one word for the poll, you will need the *.

Comment: Oh, okay.. Never used client.command so got nearly no experience ':) But you're welcome